# sklearn.utils.class_weight throws "classes should include all valid labels that can be in y" error

Tags: python, image-preprocessing

For "convenience", I tried to use sklearn.utils.class_weight, the compute_class_weight function

However, I get the "classes should include all valid labels that can be in y" error; despite that I am 100% sure that I was giving all the class labels that are there.

```
print(np.unique('y_train'), ' classes in training set')
>>> 86  classes in training set
```

So this works without problems; 
taking the len:

```
print(len(y_train), 'train samples')
>>> 6914 train samples
```

just to make sure, the shape:

```
y_train.shape
>>> (6914, 1)
```

So yes I have a vector of train samples; and I know that four or five classes are totally dominating the rest, so I wanted to add some class weight.

```
from  sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes = np.unique(y_train), y = y_train)
>>> ValueError: classes should include all valid labels that can be in y
```

And here I am. 
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it.
Thanks anyway.

the shape `(many, one)` was a problem, with `np.ravel()` it was no more a problem.

```
from  sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', classes = np.unique(y_train), y = np.ravel(y_train))
```